# App_initializer in Reactjs like in Angular or loading json file for run time configuration

Tags: reactjs, configuration, react-redux, runtime

I want to load config.json file in React application before the start of application , like run time configuration of application

this file will have some configuration in json format like

```
   {
 "env": {
  "name":"Dev"
 },

 "apiServer" : {
  "link1" :"http://amazon.com",
  "link2" :"http://ebay.com"
},

}
```

I have done this in angular using [**APP_INITIALIZER**](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-how-to-use-app-initializer/) how can I do this in React, I'm new in React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `webpack`, you might want to look into https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/ which allows you to define variables from you `webpack.config`.

If you are using Create React App, you should look into this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Comment: are these environment variable loaded in application before app startup ? @Nappy

Comment: @Asad Yes they will added to your bundle and are available from the first line of code you write.